# How to use a stub/mock in RSpec to set a instance variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec

A global variable ( `params[:something]` ) can be set only via a `get` request to a `methodA`. Now, when, `methodA` calls `methodB`, methodB has access to `params[:something]`.

I can change `methodA` to store `params` in an instance variable. If I am trying to test `methodB`, how do I use a mock/stub to call `methodA` and set those variables?

```
public
def methodA
    @instance_variable = params[:something]
    @variable = methodB (arg1, arg2)
end

private
def methodB arg1, arg2
   // needs to use params[:something] or @instance_variable
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `any_instance`

```
YourClass.any_instance.stub(:method_a).return('foo')
```

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-6/docs/method-stubs/stub-on-any-instance-of-a-class